# Combining Two Shaders into One Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, hlsl, fragment-shader

Unity Project, Want to combine these two shaders into one shader to get both of their functionality. One shader is for lighting, the other shader is for rendering better. How do I combine?

```
Shader "Transparent/Cutout/Lit3dSprite" {
Properties{
    _MainCol("Main Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _MainTex("Main Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Cutoff("Alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
}

SubShader{
    Tags {"Queue" = "AlphaTest" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "TransparentCutout" "PreviewType" = "Plane"}
    Cull Off
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf SimpleLambert alphatest:_Cutoff addshadow fullforwardshadows
    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    fixed4 _MainCol;

    half4 LightingSimpleLambert(SurfaceOutput s, half3 lightDir, half atten) 

{
            half4 c;
            c.rgb = s.Albedo * _MainCol.rgb * (atten)* _LightColor0.rgb;
            c.a = s.Alpha;
            return c;
        }

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
        };

        void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
            fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _MainCol;
            o.Albedo = lerp(c.rgb, c.rgb, c.a);
            o.Alpha = c.a;
        }
        ENDCG
    }

    Fallback "Transparent/Cutout/VertexLit"
}
```

Shader 2:

```
// Upgrade NOTE: replaced 'mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP,*)' with 'UnityObjectToClipPos(*)'

Shader "RetroAA/Sprite"
{
    Properties
    {
        [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,0,0,0)
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags {
            "Queue"="Transparent" 
            "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
            "RenderType"="Transparent" 
            "PreviewType"="Plane"
            "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
        }
        LOD 100

        Cull Off
        Lighting Off
        ZWrite Off
        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "RetroAA.cginc"

            struct appdata {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float4 color : COLOR;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f {
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                fixed4 color : COLOR;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

            float4 _Color;

            v2f vert(appdata v){
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                o.color = v.color * _Color;

                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target {
                fixed4 color = RetroAA(_MainTex, i.uv, _MainTex_TexelSize);
                return i.color*color*color.a;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: tried adding components of each but didnt work, im not proficient add shaders though

Comment: There is no way for us to know what's in `RetroAA.cginc` so an exact answer can't be given. Try this: Take your first shader, then: **1.** After the `#pragma` lines, add `#include "RetroAA.cginc"` and `float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;`. **2.** In `surf` replace `fixed4 c = ...` with `fixed4 c = RetroAA(_MainTex, i.uv, _MainTex_TexelSize);`.  You might have to change some tags and LOD and such but those two steps might combine the 2nd into the first.

Comment: #include "UnityCG.cginc"

#pragma target 3.0

fixed4 RetroAA(sampler2D tex, float2 uv, float4 texelSize){
 float2 texelCoord = uv*texelSize.zw;
 float2 hfw = 0.5*fwidth(texelCoord);
 float2 fl = floor(texelCoord - 0.5) + 0.5;
 float2 uvaa = (fl + smoothstep(0.5 - hfw, 0.5 + hfw, texelCoord - fl))*texelSize.xy;

 return tex2D(tex, uvaa);
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second shader isn't too complicated, and can be merged into the first one by just using the second shader's code to change how the first shader's `surf` calculates `fixed4 c`.

You'll also need to include the definition for `RetroAA` and include the Texel Size of the main texture in the shader variables.

However, the first shader assumes that there is no partial transparency, and the second shader requires it, so you have to accomodate that. You'll need to use Alpha blending, change the `RenderType` and `Queue` to `Transparent`, and indicate `ZWrite Off`.

Here is what that might all look together:

```
Shader "Transparent/Cutout/Lit3dSprite" {
    Properties{
        _MainCol("Main Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex("Main Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
        _Cutoff("Alpha cutoff", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
    }

        SubShader{
            // change RenderType and Queue to Transparent
            Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" "RenderType" = "Transparent" "PreviewType" = "Plane"}
            Cull Off
            ZWrite Off // Add this
            LOD 200

            // Enable Alpha blending here
            Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

            CGPROGRAM
            // Enable Alpha blending here also
            #pragma surface surf SimpleLambert alphatest:_Cutoff addshadow fullforwardshadows alpha:blend
            #pragma target 3.0

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_TexelSize; // Add this
            fixed4 _MainCol;

            // include this
            fixed4 RetroAA(sampler2D tex, float2 uv, float4 texelSize)
            {
                float2 texelCoord = uv * texelSize.zw;
                float2 hfw = 0.5*fwidth(texelCoord);
                float2 fl = floor(texelCoord - 0.5) + 0.5;
                float2 uvaa = (fl + smoothstep(0.5 - hfw, 0.5 + hfw, texelCoord - fl))*texelSize.xy;
                return tex2D(tex, uvaa);
            }

            half4 LightingSimpleLambert(SurfaceOutput s, half3 lightDir, half atten)
            {
                half4 c;

                // Fix the lambert lighting implementation here 
                half NdotL = dot(s.Normal, lightDir);

                // We set the surface rgba in surf, so don't need to do it again here.
                c.rgb = s.Albedo * (NdotL * atten) * _LightColor0.rgb;
                c.a = s.Alpha;
                return c;
            }

            struct Input {
                float2 uv_MainTex;
                float4 color: Color; // Add this to use SpriteRenderer color
            };

            void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
                // replace this line: 
                // fixed4 c = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _MainCol;

                // with this
                fixed4 c = RetroAA(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex, _MainTex_TexelSize);

                // factor in MainCol and SpriteRenderer color/tints
                o.Albedo = c.rgb * _MainCol.rgb * IN.color.rgb;
                o.Alpha = c.a * _MainCol.a * IN.color.a;
            }
            ENDCG
        }

            Fallback "Transparent/Cutout/VertexLit"
}
```

You might need to turn down the `Alpha cutoff` to zero or some other low number in order to make the AA work nicely.

Comment: Thank you, your code added most of the functionality of both shaders, except there is still an issue with the retroAA being added that it doesn't 'fully' optimize it's feature of getting rid of jaggy edges. On the right of the included picture is a sprite with just the retroAA added. And on the left is sprite the combined script. You can see the differences on the edges. Any ideas?   https://ibb.co/n3LgpWD

Comment: I realized that the second shader has alpha blending but the first does not. I edited my answer to address that. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I tried alpha cutoff to 0 and rendertype to transparent and doesn't work. Could it be we didn't transfer all the code from RetroAA - like the vertex shader, fragment shader and compile fog thing, with appdata, v2f, etc.. I tried adding those things but I don't know how to do it properly so I either get errors or the sprite turns white or pink

Comment: @David try now, I added `alpha:blend` to the first `#pragma`. If that doesn't fix it, please add another screenshot of how it looks with my answer's current code

Comment: This is pic with updated code - so it looks like it fixed the edges as far as I can tell, but there became a problem with sprite blended in behind it. or sorting or w/e  https://ibb.co/qJfFZNz

Comment: @David Ah, I'm learning quite a bit with this lol. Use `"Queue" = "Transparent"`. The `AlphaTest` queue renders from front to back, which is why the order was messed up. Since we need partial transparency to remove the aliasing, we had to get rid of the tricks that make front-to-back (which is cheaper) work properly. We just didn't change the queue accordingly! I edited my answer to use the correct queue.  Also, I think we need to turn `ZWrite Off`, try it with and without `ZWrite Off`